# How to see text of the query which triggers the trigger inside trigger?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, trigger

I have very small database with a bit complex triggers which works very slow. Those triggers are written to extend business logic (becase we can not manage the code of the application we are using). To find the problem I need to trace what happens during different SQL requests. I will log different sections of the trigger, but I need to have SQL query that causes the trigger to execute. How can I extract it from within the trigger (if it is possible) so I can write it inside my log table?

Comment: why not record all queries for selected period and then sort it by objects and operation INSER/UPDATE/DELETE. after this You can profile each single query without application

Comment: I want to make LOG table and to experiment later with the query which causes problems, @a_vlad. For this reason better way is to have query text inside the trigger, so I can save it inside the LOG table. This is my strategy to solve the issue.

Comment: I not answer on Your main question - I not sure. I just suggest You other way. Because You already have problems - if (IF You found solution), You make situation only more bad. so I suggest go traditional way - trace slow query and go deep understanding which triggers they fire. You still have triggers for DELETE/UPDATE/INSERT so if You have list of slow query, You can easy select triggers and profile full cycle.

Comment: I now got your point. I agree with you that I will make situation even worse. I will try what you suggested. Thanks, @a_vlad.